# What is the unit of $\mathbb Z_1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have almost solved a question which is as follows $:$

$U(\mathbb Z_n) \cong \mathbb Z_{\phi (n)}$ for $1 \leq n \leq 7$ where $U(\mathbb Z_n)$ denotes the set of all units of $\mathbb Z_n$ and $\phi$ denotes Euler's $\phi$ function.

I have proved it for $2 \leq n \leq 7$ since it is pretty straight forward. But the problem is created due to $n=1$. Because we know that $\mathbb Z_1 = \{\bar 0 \}$. But then $U(\mathbb Z_1) = \emptyset$ which cannot even a group as each group is non-empty and at least contains the identity element of it.

I don't know where I have made mistakes. Please help me in overcoming such misconception (if any).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the trivial ring, the trivial element is not only an additive identity, it is also a multiplicative identity (or in other words, $0\equiv 1$ mod $1$). Therefore in this context $0$ is itself invertible, and your unit group is in fact $\{0\}$, which is the trivial group under the multiplication operation.

Comment: Oh! That's a fine answer really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part where you go wrong is saying that $U(\mathbb{Z}_1) = \varnothing$, when in fact, $U(\mathbb{Z}_1) = \mathbb{Z}_1$. Obviously the forward containment is true, so we only need to show that if $x \in \mathbb{Z}_1$, then $x$ is multiplicatively invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_1$. So, if $x \in \mathbb{Z}_1$, then $x = 0$, for rather obvious reasons. Then, $0 \cdot 0 \equiv 1 \cdot 1 \equiv 1 \mod 1$, so $0$ is multiplicatively invertible mod $1$, and we are done.